# Simple string mistake

Tags: java, string, prompt, mutation

I am trying to create a string method in java where it prompts someone to enter a string longer than three characters. Once entered, I want to display the middle three characters of that string. Something is wrong because it is not compiling. Can anyone see my mistake? I can't find it. Thanks.

```
//MyString.java
import java.util.Scanner; 
 public class MyString .java {


    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {    

String string;


Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println ("Enter a string with a minimum of three characters: " + string); 
string = scan.nextLine();

System.out.println ("You entered: " + string);

String middle3;

System.out.println ("The middle three characters of the string: " + middle3);


    }


}
```

Comment: What error do you get from the compiler?

Comment: '{' expected in line 10 -(the public class line)

Comment: what does the ".java" next to "public class MyString" mean? It should be removed. Anyway, it looks like your code doesn't perform any manipulations on input string.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyString .java {
```

this is wrong. remove ". java"

Answer (score 3):

You are using `MyString .java` as the class name. Java does not allow space and period to be part of a valid class name. I guess you meant `MyString`.

Also variables `string` and `middle3` are not initialized before their use.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually calculating middle3. It isn't even initialized to null. I imagine you want:

```
String middle3 = (string.length < 3) ? null : string.substring(string.length / 2 - 1), string.length / 2 + 2);
```

or something like that.

Comment: it didn't work. How could I get it to display the middle three characters?

Comment: What didn't work? What was the input; what was the output? What do you want printed if the string is shorter than 3 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you append string here?

```
 System.out.println ("Enter a string with a minimum of three characters: " + string );
```

here you should initialize `middle`:

```
String middle3 ="something";    
System.out.println ("The middle three characters of the string: " + middle3);
```